# Python 3: Basic Spell Check

Tags: python, python-3.x, spell-checking

```
#SPELL CHECK PROGRAM
def SpellCheck():

    import difflib
    import urllib.request

    #Downloads 10000 most used english words as txt file
    url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/first20hours/google-10000-english/master/google-10000-english.txt'
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = response.read()      #
    text = data.decode('utf-8') #

    x = True
    while x == True:
        print("Enter your word: ")
        word = input(">>  ")

        clr(2)
        s(3)

        if (word.lower()) in text:
            print(word, " is spelt correctly")

        else:
            print("It doesn't seem like i know that word")

            #closewords = difflib.get_close_matches(word, text)
            wrongcount = 0
            correctcount = 0
            closewords = []

            ############

            for x in text:
                wrongcount = 0
                correctcount = 0

                for let in x:
                    for letter in word:
                        if let == letter:
                            correctcount += 1
                        else:
                            wrongcount +=1

                    if correctcount > len(word) - 4:
                        closewords.append(x)

                    else:
                        x = 0

            #############

            print("Perhaps you meant one of these: ")
            print( closewords )

        print("Would you like to try again?")
        again = input(">>  ")

        if again == 'Y' or again ==  'y' or again ==  'yes' or again ==  'Yes':
            x = True
        else:
            print("Okay")
            x = False
```

It *Should* take a list of the 10,000 most used english words and turn them into a list.
if the user's word doesn't match one of the ones in the list it should:
for every letter in every word check to see if the letter matches that of the one in the user's word.
use this to see if any/many of the letters match in the two words. If they do, print it in a list of suggestions.

If the inputted word is spelt correctly; it will print that it is spelt correctly

If the inputed word is spelt incorrectly; it will print that it is spelt wrong, but it wont give any suggestions, even if for example; (I input 'pooison', it wont come up with anything, even though 'poison' is in the *dictionary*)

It should in that case print out 'poison'

Comment: The question being? Is it that it simply does not work? What does it do? Does any of it work?

Comment: Some of it works, but it doesn't print out any suggestions.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include what it currently displays when run and what you expect instead?

Comment: Your algorithm for detecting if a word is similar to another seems to be incorrect. Why don't you use difflib, it looked like you were trying to, you just need to convert your text into a list of words, ie. `print "similar words are:",difflib.get_close_matches(word.lower(),text.splitlines())`

Comment: That seems to have worked, thanks so much mate.

Answer (score 1):

For the suggestions - don't use your approach. A potentially more rigorous way of suggesting close words is using a [smith waterman type alignment algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm).

The basic idea is that you declare penalties for letter mismatches and insertions in one of the words. You can then, simply select the works in the dictionary that have a matching score that is greater than a certain threshold. The algorithm for words of length n and m is O(mn), so should be pretty reasonable for 10k short words.

Implementation-wise, this algorithm is used mostly for genetic sequence approximate matching, so most of the python implementations are geared towards this. If you can't find a general implementation, it might be worthwhile writing your own as a learning exercise. I can give you some pointers if you want?

Example

```html
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

def sub_function(letter1, letter2):
    
    if letter1 == letter2:
        return 1 #increase score if letter match
    else:
        return -1 # decrease score if letter mismatch

        
#######################################################        


def needleman_wunsch(si,sj,d=-2):
    #dimensions
    I =len(si)+1 ; J = len(sj)+1
        
    #define a dynamic programming matrix+backpointer matrix as a numpy array
    DP=np.zeros([len(si)+1,len(sj)+1]); PTR = DP.copy()

    #initialise top and left edges with the ga[ penalties
    for i in range(0,DP.shape[0]):
        DP[i,0]=d*(i)
    for i in range(0,DP.shape[1]):
        DP[0,i]=d*(i)
    
    #iterations over DP matrix, generate PTR matrix to all reconstruction 
    for i in range(1,I):
        for j in range(1,J):
            F_ij =[DP[i,j-1]+d,DP[i-1,j]+d,DP[i-1,j-1]+sub_function(si[i-1],sj[j-1])]
            DP[i,j]=max(F_ij)
            PTR[i,j]=F_ij.index(DP[i,j])
    
    #reconstructed strings 
    sI='';sJ=''
    l_c = [I-1,J-1]; p_c=PTR[l_c[0],l_c[1]]
    
    #main loop
    while l_c[0] >0 and l_c[1] >0:
        i=l_c[0]-1; j=l_c[1]-1 # character indices
        if PTR[l_c[0],l_c[1]] ==2:
            sI+=si[i]; sJ+=sj[j];
            l_c=[l_c[0]-1,l_c[1]-1] 
        elif PTR[l_c[0],l_c[1]] ==1:
            l_c=[l_c[0]-1,l_c[1]]
            sI+=si[i]; sJ+='-';
        elif PTR[l_c[0],l_c[1]] ==0:
            l_c=[l_c[0],l_c[1]-1]
            sI+='-'; sJ+=sj[j];
        
    #reversing strings as loop builds them backwards
    sI=sI[::-1]; sJ=sJ[::-1]
   
    return (sI,sJ,DP[-1,-1]) # a tuple of the two string+ score
    
def display(nw_tuple):
    print nw_tuple[0]
    print nw_tuple[1]
    print 'score: '+str(nw_tuple[2])
    

match= needleman_wunsch('acknowledgment','acknowlefdgment')
display(match)
```

Comment: Could you perhaps put together an example?

Comment: certainly, check out my answer (this is 2.7 though...)

Comment: you would want to select any words that have a high match. (Notice that the length of the word is important here - the selection of the exact parameters are a function of the properties of the two strings being aligned)